# How to Scroll In an Android Tab Using UIAutomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

i am trying to Scroll Using UIAutomator. The Scenario is I am entering the Settings menu in the tab and clicking on Apps options which gives me a list of all the apps in the tab. NOw i want to scroll the list of apps and this is where i am facing issues.It scrolls the Settings options and not the App list. I am attaching a screen shot and my piece of code.

```
            UiScrollable scroll = new UiScrollable(
                    new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
            scroll.setAsVerticalList();

            UiObject Apps = scroll.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
                    .className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()),
                    "Apps");
            Apps.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
            UiObject Locker = scroll.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()),"Content Locker");
            Locker.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am new to UiAutomator too and there is not very big amount of tutorials to learn it. I used Smrti example here, but some of the things already got deprecated, so I corrected it a bit to make everything work. Here's what I got

```
 UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
    mDevice.pressHome();

    UiObject allAppsButton = mDevice
            .findObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps"));

    allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    UiScrollable appViews = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

    appViews.scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Settings"));
    mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Settings")).clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps")).click();
```

I didn't include the search for certain app here, I'm sure you can manage it the same way as searching for the Settings app in my code snippet.

Comment: Would it be possible to import and perform in Appium Java

Answer (score 3):

Say I want to click on App Facebook which is a little down the Apps list under Settings.

You can use this -

```
 getUiDevice().pressHome();
 allAppsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps"));
 allAppsButton.click();

 appViews = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
 appViews.setAsHorizontalList();
 selector = new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName());

 appToLaunch = appViews.getChildByText(selector, "Settings");
 if (appToLaunch != null)
    appToLaunch.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps")).click();

    UiScrollable appViews1 = new UiScrollable(newUiSelector().scrollable(true));

    appViews1.scrollForward();
    appViews1.scrollTextIntoView("Facebook");
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Facebook")).click();
```

This should work.